# Simple division of odd numbers not working in C programming

Tags: c

I'm sure I'm missing something extremely simply since I'm very new to this, but for some reason when I divide an odd number by 2 and then multiply the result, the program will only multiply by the number rounded down, for example when I divide 5 by 2 and then multiply that, it only multiplies it by 2, not even 2.5. What I am eventually trying to do is have it so it rounds up so that dividing 5 by 2 would become 3, but for whatever reason it rounds down now automatically. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int num_containers;
    float price, total, num_half;

printf("What is the cost of one container?\n");
scanf("%f", &price);

printf("How many containers are you buying?\n");
scanf("%d", &num_containers);

num_half = num_containers / 2;
total = num_half * price;

if(num_containers % 2 == 0)
    printf("The total cost is $%.2f.\n", num_containers / 2 * price);
else
    printf("The total cost is $%f.\n", num_containers / 2 * price);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want a rounded division in integer arithmetic, add an adjustment before doing the divide. For example to divide by `10` and round, add `5` first.

Comment: or if dividing by 2, add 1 first. num_half = (num_containers+1) / 2;

Answer (score 3):

`num_containers` is defined as int, when you divide it by 2 it is rounded down.

Comment: It is rounded down when the quotient is positive, else rounded up.  IAC, the fraction is discarded.

Answer (score 2):

The expression

```
num_containers / 2;
```

is evaluated as integer division since both operands are integers, resulting in an integer. There's no way to represent the remaining `0.5` in an integer, so it is lost.

For comparison, the expression

```
0.5 * num_containers;
```

includes a floating-point literal, so `num_containers` is promoted to a double first, and the result is a double (`num_containers / 2.0` does the same).

Since everything *apart from* `num_containers` is a float, skipping the intermediate value would have worked:

```
total = num_containers * price / 2;
```

---

Note, in order to force rounding *up*, you can either do it explicitly with [`ceil`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/ceil)

```
total = ceil(num_containers / 2.0) * price;
```

or stay in integer land and simply add one:

```
int more_than_half = (num_containers + 1) / 2;
```

Comment: The OP stated that he wants 5/2 to result in a rounded up 3.

Comment: You can delete or edit your answer if you want. I'll delete this comment and my previous comment later.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `num_containers` is defined as an int. If you do operations including an int and a float, the result will become a float. You're dividing an int by an int, so the result is an int.

If you want a float result, first cast `num_containers` to a float, or, if you're always dividing by the literal '2', change it to 2.0f.

Comment: _"If you do operations including an int and a float..."_ the integer will be promoted. The problem is that _both_ operands are integers in this case.

Comment: you're right, I goofed all my words up. Edited to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `num_containers` is an integer, and so the expression `num_containers / 2` will resolve to a rounded integer value.  If you declare it as `float num_containers`, you should get the desired result, or you can cast it as a floating point value whenever you use it in an expression.  For example:

```
num_half = (float) num_containers / 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a rounded division in integer arithmetic, add an adjustment before doing the divide. For example to divide by 10 and round, add 5 first. In your case of dividing by 2

```
num_half = (num_containers + 1) / 2;
```

Which will round 5 / 2 up to 3.